# What is keeping me from using Ember.testing = true?

Tags: testing, ember.js

I'd like to set `Ember.testing = true` for my unit tests. I wrote lots of tests with it off (`false`) and now when I try to turn it on, I get

> 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'loop.schedule')

Of course, I can set `Ember.testing = false` for specific tests, but I'd like to figure out the root problem. What is it that I'm doing in my tests that is incompatible with this setting?

Comment: Are you using RC1 or the current master?

Comment: Good question. Neither. This is on Ember 0.9.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

You might still need to User Ember.run() to run things.

You might find [this article](http://darthdeus.github.com/blog/2013/02/19/testing-ember-dot-js-part-1/) helpful.